# Summary Statistics with multiple case fields not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, error-999999, summarizing

While trying to calculate summary statistics in a table in a GDB, i get the following error:

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table was not found. [OutputStats]
Failed to execute (Summary Statistics).
```

The "OutputStats" table is the output of the Summary Statistics tool.

The input table table is in the following format:

```
Address       | Period | Consumed
1 Example str | 1/2016 |    18
1 Example str | 2/2016 |    17
2 Example str | 1/2016 |    19
2 Example str | 2/2016 |    23
```

The table has 300k lines but i have worked with larger ones without problem.

I use "Consumed" as the statistics field with "sum" as Type with "Period" and "Address" as the case fields.

Note that "address" and "period" are text fields and "consumed" is Numeric.
When i use only one of the above case fields the tool works ok.
I have tried both ArcGIS 10.5 and ArcGIS Pro 1.4 with no success.
I am calling the tool in Model Builder but i also tried it from the toolbox as a standalone tool. 
In Model Builder i also tried a Table View as input without success.

I think the problem is with the input table but i can not see why.

[image: SummaryError]

Comment: Ive experienced this before, if you try to a different gdb or different format does it work?

Comment: You do not show the obvious which is how you called the tool, amend your question to include a screen shot showing us what the input parameters are.

Comment: I use this tool with both Desktop and Pro and multiple case items on an almost daily basis and do not recall ever seeing it 999999 so I think you need to look closely at your data and parameter values.

Comment: I have edited the question. I state how the tool is called and included a screenshot

Comment: If this is a consistently reproducible problem with this specific data, it could quite likely be a software bug. Could you share the data?

Comment: Should the output table have a file path with it?

Answer (score 0):

To try and reproduce this using ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1, I used the Create Table tool to create a test table, and then used the Add Field tool to add two text fields (Address and Period) and a short integer field (Consumed).  I edited my test table to update it with the same values you showed and then ran Summary Statistics using the same statistics field and type, and the same two case fields that you did.  You can see this below.

[image]

The tool ran without a problem so I am unable to reproduce your problem.  If the same simple test produces an error for you, or if it only produces an error on a larger dataset, then I recommend that you submit it to your local Esri support.